# $Gcd(f,g)\neq 1$ implies that $f$ and $g$ have a common root in some extension of the base field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have to prove that for two polynomials $\;f,g \in F[x]\;$ , we have that $\;
gcd(f,g) \neq 1\;$ iff there exists $\;a \in K\;$ which is in some extension field of $F$ and $f(a)=g(a)=0$

I tried to use Euclid's algorithm and to get the gcd of the polynomials but what is its properties?

Comment: You really should both improve your english writing and ust MathJax, as used in this site.

Comment: I would lead off with telling Readers that $F$ is a field.  It can be surmised from the context that $F$ must be the "base field" mentioned in the title, but it is good practice to give a full problem statement in the body of the Question.

Comment: Hint: show that $gcd(f,g)$ in $F[x]$ is the same with $gcd(f,g)$ in $K[x]$ for every field $K\supset F$

Answer (score 4):

If $\gcd(f,g)=1$, then there exist polynomials $u,v$ with $uf+vg=1$, hence $f$ and $g$ cannot have a root in common.

If $\gcd(f,g)=h$ is a non-constant polynomial, then any root of $h$ (in a suitable extension field $K$) is of course also a root of $f$ and of $g$.

Comment: Why h must be polynomial & not a scalar different than 1?